# Zend Framework: How do I utilize MVC for our mobile website

Tags: model-view-controller, zend-framework, design-patterns

Ok so i have our online ordering going, its a module that i have called 'olo'. What i need now is to build a mobile version our website, totally different layout and design.

Now, how do i utilize the power of MVC, that had me sold once i started?

I want to use all the different controller classes that i have allready created in the OLO module.

Right now i have started the development of our mobile website, it's placed as another module called 'mobile'. It's build with jQuery Mobile, and i allready have quite a bit done; info-pages, contact form, etc.

All mobile devices are currently redirected to `domain.tld/m` with [.htacces mobile dectection](http://detectmobilebrowser.com/). This is done to support full-website view if linked to from mobile version.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

With **Zend Framework 1.11** zend introduced the [**wurfl adapter**](http://framework.zend.com/manual/en/zend.http.user-agent-features-wurfl.html) which is based on [**Zend_Http_UserAgent**](http://framework.zend.com/manual/en/zend.http.user-agent.html#zend.http.user-agent.quick-start).

It allows you to detect mobile devices and bootstrap different layouts. There is a HOW TO on youtube that came with the zend newsletter december 2010: http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=_A8yg73tqOY

You don't have to use different modules! Just different layout files!

Comment: From what i can understand your way is the one to go. If i would like to give the mobile users a link to our non-mobile website, could this be done with the wurfl setup?

Comment: Yes, you could provide a simple link somewhere in the footer maybe which sets a flag using zend registry and check this flag where you check the mobile devices, http://www.dotkernel.com/dotkernel/disable-automatic-wurfl-redirect/

Comment: Nice, this is very interesting. I'm not sure if i will use it right now, i think it will take a bit to much rewrite of existing code. And i need to get this going now, CEOs always need things done yesterday - you know :)

Comment: For advanced view/layout switching like the contextSwitch action helper, I wrote a short article about this with help of WURFL: http://juriansluiman.nl/en/article/111/mobile-detection-with-zend_http_useragent

Answer (score 3):

Personally, I'd use front controller plugin. Doing this inside bootstrap is a little too early step in a process for my concern.

Write a plugin that hooks preDispatch() and uses Zend_Http_UserAgent to find if application is being accessed via mobile device. Then you can [set view script path](http://framework.zend.com/manual/en/zend.view.scripts.html) to another directory. For example, let's say **default** is your current view directory, **mobile** is your new view directory. You just clone the structure and modify files and it should do the trick :)

```
application/
  modules/
    olo/
      controllers/
      modules/
      views/
         scripts/
           default/
           mobile/
```

Comment: Ok i maybe should have mentioned this, but i have a [.htaccess mobile detection](http://detectmobilebrowser.com/) that redirects all mobile devices to `domain.tld/m` and a routes.ini-file that handles /m and all sub-paths. But your comment on the different dirs in the scripts directory, is probably of good use.

Comment: You could also match that using router (don't recall what exact method, will update the answer tomorrow). That way all your controllers and models stay the same, and as ArtWorkAD stated, only layouts are changed. Also take a look at his advice, using wurfl wouldn't be bad either. You'll have less problems in the future, since you won't have to write upgrades twice for normal and mobile version, because logic stays the same :)

Comment: I have accepted @ArtWorkAD 's answer, but your was also very helpful - Have som rep :)

Answer (score 3):

Like ArtWorkAD said you can use in Zend Framework 1.11 the wurfl adapter that allow you to detect  user agent and switch the layout but that mean each of you view need to be "universal". I never so "universal" view so far.

What you can use is the ContextSwitch of the View
http://framework.zend.com/manual/en/zend.controller.actionhelpers.html#zend.controller.actionhelpers.contextswitch

It lets you create different context, it is normally use to create a csv/xml file.
Let say you have a controller called Index with an action called FooAction(), I assume you already have a view scripts/index/foo.phtml

You can create a context called "mobile", which will allow you to create a view for that context like that scripts/index/foo.mobile.phtml .
It's like changing layout but for a view and with the previous wurfl adapter you could change the layout an automatically switch the context.

Comment: I have accepted @ArtWorkAD 's answer, but your was also very helpful - Have som rep :)